# unbootable disk - hdd not detected at bios - I'm able to mount data from livecd -

Tags: debian, hard-disk

recently I have updated my debian and then at reboot I received an "insert bootable media" error. Then I checked the bios where hdd is not detected.

Next, I have mounted data from live cd (gparted) and I have successfully red filesystem. How it is possibile? Changing disk... it is detected.

Thx

Comment: Please describe how you "checked the BIOS" and what you saw. If the BIOS does not detect a disk, it can't boot from it. But you could boot your old system from it...

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. If the BIOS does not detect the hard drive, it cannot be mounted. I think you're confusing the BIOS being unable to detect "bootable media" with being unable to detect the hard drive.

In short, it sounds like the BIOS is detecting the hard drive just fine, but can't boot the operating system on it for some reason.